# How to get export from igraph in python?

Tags: python, matrix, igraph

I wrote this code to convert data in .gml format but I got this error. what should I do?

```
TypeError: descriptor 'write_gml' for 'igraph._igraph.GraphBase' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

code:

```
import igraph as ig
import pandas as pd


a = pd.DataFrame(Matrix, index=tags, columns=tags)


# # Get the values as np.array, it's more convenenient.
A = a.values
# print(A)
# # Create graph, A.astype(bool).tolist() or (A / A).tolist() can also be used.
g = igraph.Graph.Adjacency((A > 0).tolist())

# # Add edge weights and node labels.
g.es['weight'] = A[A.nonzero()]
g.vs['label'] = tags  # or a.index/a.columns

ig.Graph.write_gml('test.gml')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `g.write_gml(filename)` if you want to write the graph `g` to `filename`.